# CURL grab information and log in with it

Tags: php, curl

i got a problem.
i want to log in a website with CURL, but the page generates a key, which is in a hidden field. So I have to grab the value of the hidden field... after that i have to submit the password, the email AND the the grabbed key.

Is that possible?

hope you understand

Thanks

----edit----
if the page reload, there's a new key in the hidden field.. and the old one do not work

Comment: There must be something in the http header to tell whether the key is a valid / expired, maybe you try to investigate it, once you have the correct header you can send a request after grabbing the key manually or by parsing the HTML result of curl.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. The basic steps would be:

```
1. Fetch form
2. Run returned data through DOMdocument to extract the hidden form field's value
3. Post login data, including the key value from step #2
4. ???
5. Profit
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

1. Load the page contents into a variable (eg. `$contents = file_get_contents(...);`).
2. Now, parse it so you can get the hidden key (eg. `$matches = preg_match(..., ...); $key = $matches[1];`).
3. Now, post the request using the hidden key (eg. `$context = streamcontextcreate(...); $data = file_get_contents(..., false, $context);`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can even grab the page with

> $source = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($url));

Then use strpos, substr and so on to get information of that field (that's the easiest way)

Then just POST it with this function

> $urltopost = $url
>
> $datatopost = array ($name => $value);
>
> $ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
>
> curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
>
> curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
>
> curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>
> $returndata = htmlspecialchars(curl_exec ($ch));

Comment: why `htmlspecialchars()`? Totally unnecessary when the OP just needs to extract a single value from the form. The page data won't be re-displayed anywhere.

Comment: Well, I always use it because I have trouble doing strpos with Lithuanian letters then.

Comment: Should be using mb_strpos() in that case, which is multibyte aware and works with UTF strings.